# How to add spacing between currency and amount which is inside a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

##### My string in Ruby contains currency and amount.

I have purchased and item at USD500.80 from online store store 123X87

##### I am expecting following result

I have purchased and item at USD 500.80 from online store store 123X87

##### I tried with Regex but not succeed.

```
str = "I have purchased and item at USD500.80 from online store store 123X87"

str.gsub(/\d+/, ' \0 ')

# wrong result

"I have purchased and item at USD 500 . 80  from online store store  123 X 87 "
```

I am not sure what currency that string contains. I only know currency and amount do not have space.

```
str = "I have purchased and item at EUR500.80 from online store store 123X88"

str = "I have purchased and item at GBP500.80 from online store store 123X88"
```

Comment: It might be enough to write `str.gsub(/(?<=[A-Z]{3})(?=\d+\.\d{2}\b)/, ' ')`. This is a zero-width match preceded by three capital letters and followed by one or more digits, a period and then two more digits. `(?<=[A-Z]{3})` is a *positive lookbehind* and `(?=\d+\.\d{2}\b)` is a *positive lookahead*. Some adjustments probably are necessary. For example, some amounts may contain commas or no period. Perhaps `/(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)/` would be sufficient (that is, insert a space after a capital letter that is immediately followed by a digit).

Comment: I think it might be a problem when you do not know what currency the string contains. Because it depends on the currency and the locale if the [currency symbol is in front of the amount or behind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Position_of_ISO_4217_code_in_amounts). And also important: There are different decimal separators in use in different countries. That said: Might it be possible that you have to handle amounts like `"... 500,80EUR ..."` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd change the regex to scan for all known currency codes explicitly. Any over-generalized regex (such as `\w+\d+`, for example) is bound to break other parts of the string, like order numbers.

```rb
str = "I have purchased and item at USD500.80 from online store store 123X87"
str.gsub(/(USD|EUR)(\d+)/, '\1 \2')
# => "I have purchased and item at USD 500.80 from online store store 123X87"
```

Comment: Updated my question. If I am using 100's of currency and In case I don't know which currency has been used inside string, what will be your suggestion?

Comment: @sivrj My suggestion will be the same. It's still a finite list.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes